# Windows 7 gadget flyout window question

Tags: windows-desktop-gadgets

I created a gadget that displays the feed from a website and displays it in the main window.
If I click on one of the news I get the flyout window and it gives me more information. 
I also have a search option in the main body, that does the search on the site but it opens in the browser window.

My question is how can I make the search function open in the flyout window?
Is there a way to link the search button to a flyout_2 file?
Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

**Flyout windows must be opened manually.**

The entire interface is soup. A flyout must also be pointed to a valid HTML page (locally or remotely, it doesn't matter). *Once loaded, however, you can treat the DOM however you like.*

That being said, capture the "search" event and make it display to the flyout DOM. This could be with a redirect of the flyout itself, an iframe with a dynamically set target, or other DOM manipulation.

One trick I have used is to use a "generic" flyout which simply invokes a method on the parent window passing in itself as a parameter (flyouts are are just child windows) and then let the "main" gadget actually handle the DOM work based on context.

```
// in "fuout.html"
jQuery(function ($j) {
    var parent = System.Gadget.document
    parent.loadFuout(document, $j)
})

// in main gadget html
document.loadFuout = function (fuout, _j) {
    // other stuff based on current flyout context...
    // fuout is document object of flyout
}
```

**Please note:** in my case I run a slightly modified jQuery in which document is bound in a closure. This allows me to refer to the "correct jQuery object for the document", above that is accessed via _j.

Comment: Is a bit above my pay-grade. I am trying to find something more simple or something that I know how to use. Thx anyway.